# Context Argument in Toast.maketext()

Tags: android, android-toast

this is my first post here. I used the search function and could not find a complete answer,so I hope this is not a redundant question.
I should note that I m really new to coding so maybe I did find an answer but did not realise it.

I have been asked in class to find two different ways to fill the argument in the code below.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(???,"Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

the first way i suppose would be toast.makeText(MainActivity.this.getActivity(),....).show();

the second one?

Comment: you can use the context of the view.

Comment: as to how to solve such question: you are looking for a context. Look at all the objects you have in scope (here, mainly, `this` and `v`), and look at which extend context, and which have methods that return contexts.

Comment: `v.getContext()`..., `getApplicationContext()` etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the MainActivity context.

```
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: so both MainActivity.this and MainActivity.this.getActivity are correct?

Answer (score 0):

`v.getContext()` and `this` both can be used